# Python 3.6 Beautiful Soup - Attribute Error

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.6

## I can import BeautifulSoup using Python 2.7 but not when I try using Python 3.6, even though BeautifulSoup claims to work on both?

## Sorry this is my first question so apologies if it's trivial or if I haven't used the proper conventions.

> > > from BeautifulSoup import *
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/Users/tobiecusson/Desktop/Python/Ch3-PythonForWebData/AssignmentWeek4/BeautifulSoup.py", line 448
> > >           raise AttributeError, "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.**class**.**name**, attr)
> > >                               ^
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> > >
> > > from BS4 import BeautifulSoup
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/Users/tobiecusson/Desktop/Python/Ch3-PythonForWebData/AssignmentWeek4/BS4.py", line 448
> > >           raise AttributeError, "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.**class**.**name**, attr)
> > >                               ^
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed - you're importing from `BeautifulSoup`.
Try `from bs4 import *`

Comment: Thanks Dimitriy, I tried to implement your fix but unfortunately it didn't solve my issue.